# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - jQuery tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I am getting the following error in Chrome dev console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

My understanding is that it is because `.browser` is now deprecated in jQuery however I am using the latest version of jQuery tools and it is still giving the error, I checked in the `js` file and it is there.

How can I get around this so it does not give the error?

Comment: this error is insufficient. From what element are you trying to read this from?

Comment: I haven't used `.browser` in my code at all. It seems to be detecting it in the jQuery tools file.

Comment: The `browser` object is not only *deprecated* in 1.9, it's *gone*.  If jQuery Tools is still using it, then jQuery Tools is broken.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using `$.browser` or not. If any of your dependencies is using then you need it

Comment: @Colin747, having said that, can you try using the jQuery Migrate Plugin as described in the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/)?

Comment: @Alexander that seemed to get rid of the error. You can put an answer up if you like.

Comment: @Colin747, I believe you can set `jQuery.migrateMute` and `jQuery.migrateTrace` to `false`

Comment: @Alexander I found a CDN that doesn't produce logging but thanks, if you want to put an answer up I'll accept

Comment: @Colin747, ok, i will post it

Comment: The latest jQuery Tools has only been tested with jQuery 1.7.  jQuery 1.9 is not compatible with the latest version of jQuery Tools; it's that simple.  Dump jQuery Tools or downgrade jQuery to any version below 1.9 that works.  Otherwise, don't expect anyone to update jQuery Tools, it's been without a developer for the last few years.

Comment: is this error related to using admin with overlay mode?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

The `$.browser` method has been removed as of jQuery 1.9.

> [**`jQuery.browser() removed`**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)
>
> The `jQuery.browser()` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and is removed in 1.9. **If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery Migrate plugin.** We recommend using feature detection with a library such as Modernizr.
>
> — [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/).

As stated in the Upgrade Guide you can try using the [jQuery Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to restore this functionality and let jQuery Tools work.

Answer (score 285):

You can check out this solution by AJ. It's pretty straightforward, just copy and paste the following lines of code.

```
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
})();
```

**Reference**:

- <del>[$.browser on jQuery 1.9.x for legacy IE detection](http://n33.co/2013/03/23/browser-on-jquery-19x-for-legacy-ie-detection)</del>

Comment: This works Perfect! But I take it this should be used as a patch, rather than a solution right?

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, since IE11 does not have the MSIE token in the `userAgent` string.

Comment: I put this code but it is not working for Chrome browser!

Answer (score 54):

Use the following script tag in your jsp/js file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

this will work for sure.

Comment: make sure you have working internet connection. If you are using offline then download the js file at your end, and then refer that file.

Comment: Well I can see that it is hosted online... anyways thanks I resolved it with jquery.noConflict() as I had two versions to jquery being used on the same page.

Comment: @User5590 : anytime :)

Comment: Shouldn't use non minified jquery in production : check https://cdnjs.com for example.
And use HTTPS instead.

Answer (score 35):

I use below code after js file include and it's working now.

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.browser = {};
    (function () {
        jQuery.browser.msie = false;
        jQuery.browser.version = 0;
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
            jQuery.browser.msie = true;
            jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: This link [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) gives me error, but this little piece of code you wrote helped me a lot, thanks man.

Answer (score 11):

I've simply added

```
jQuery.browser = {
    msie: false,
    version: 0
};
```

after jquery script, because I don't care about IE anymore.

Comment: Thank bro. I got those type of error and solved my issue which is provided by your solution.

Answer (score 7):

[Here is the jQuery Tools bug on GitHub](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/928).  You can try one of the patches.

*edit* — it doesn't look to me as if jQuery Tools is getting much support.  I personally would not begin a new project with a dependency on that library unless I were prepared to take over support myself.

Comment: +1, jQuery Tools has been a complete mess for the last few years. That it's not "getting much support" is very accurate and a huge understatement. I think there's only been one minor update since jQuery 1.3 and no developer for the last couple of years as well.

Comment: Agreed, does anyone have a recommendation for a replacement library? Something with a scroller, overlay and range input slider? I avoid jQuery mobile because it comes pre-styled. I have styled it before and it's a nightmare.

Comment: I've moved to just finding well written minimal libraries for each function I want.  ie: range input slider: http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/, scroller/slider: http://bxslider.com/. I find much better support and and overall smaller footprint finding individual libraries like these

Answer (score 3):

As I don't plan to support old MS IE versions at all, I've simply replaced all references to `browser.msie` with `false`.
Not a nice solution, I know, but it works for me.

(Actually, they appeared as `!browser.msie`, which could be omitted from the conditions.)

Answer (score 3):

Replace Your JS with

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Source [link](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: At the moment for jquery 1.7+ the latest jquery-ui is:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

See this issue mainly rises due to browser navigation and version properties.
For this you have to add just following code in function :

```
/* solution to undefined msie */
jQuery.browser = {};
jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
/* solution to undefined msie */
```

For exapmle I am using it on click function, see it:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.remove_add_test', function() {
    var product_id = $(this).data('id');
    var thisproduct = $(this);
    
    /* solution to undefined msie */
    jQuery.browser = {};
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
        jQuery.browser.version = 0;
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
            jQuery.browser.msie = true;
            jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
        }
    /* solution to undefined msie */    
    
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete record?', 'Remove Product', function(r) {
        if (r == true) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'scripts/ajax/index.php',
                data: {
                    method: 'removeproduct_fromcart',
                    id: product_id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.RESULT == 0) {
                        $(".price span").text(data.totalprice);
                        $(thisproduct).closest('tr').remove();
                        $(".cart-number").text(data.productcount - 1);
                        $.growl.notice({
                            title: "Shopping Cart",
                            message: data.MSG
                        });
                       location.reload();
                        // window.location.href = 'https://www.youth-revisited.co.uk/payment.html';

                    }
                    // window.location.href = 'https://www.youth-revisited.co.uk/payment.html';
                }
            });
            // window.location.href = 'https://www.youth-revisited.co.uk/payment.html';

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like blow

```
$(function (a) {
```

. . . . .then in your function you can using msie property like

```
if (a.browser.msie) 
{
}
else 
{
   $(settings.current).after(Uploadelement);
}
```

goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Use like blow

i use this command and solve

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined" Error

```
if (/1\.(0|1|2)\.(0|1|2)/.test($.fn.jquery) || /^1.1/.test($.fn.jquery)) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while using JQuery 1.10 and JQuery UI 1.8. I was able to resolve this error by updating to the latest JQuery UI 1.11.4.

### Steps to update JQuery UI from Visual Studio:

- Navigate to Project or Solution
- Right click: "Manage NuGet Packages"
- On the left, click on "Installed Packages" tab
- Look for "JQuery UI (Combined library)" and click Update
- If found, Select it and click Update
- If not found, find it in "Online > nuget.org" tab on the left and click install. If the old version of Jquery UI version is still existing, it can be deleted from the project

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery defined twice, then you could get this error. For example, if you are working with Primefaces (it already includes jQuery) and you define it in other place.