# Jquery Validation Not Working with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Hi I am doing simple form registration validation using jquery. Only thing is i have used boot strap framework.

When I click on registration button noting will happen;

In fire bug console it display

```
[09:35:37.239] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://www.matrimonyteam.com/home/registration
```

For more information you go thru this url **http://www.matrimonyteam.com/home/registration**

```
function register(){

    var validator = $("#profileRegistrationForm").validate({
        rules: {                            
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required",
            email: "required",
            loginPassword: "required",
            mobileNumber: "required",       
            gender: "required",
            birthDate: "required",
            motherTongue: "required"
        },
        errorElement: "span",                               
            messages: {
            firstName: "Enter First Name",
            lastName: "Enter Last Name",
            email: "Enter Valid Email Address",
            loginPassword: "Enter Password",
            mobileNumber: "Enter Mobile Number",        
            gender: "Select Your Gender",
            birthDate: "Select Birth Date",
            motherTongue: "Select Mother Tongue"
            }
    });
    if(validator.form()){ 
         $('form#profileRegistrationForm').attr({action: '/home/saveprofile'});         
         $('form#profileRegistrationForm').submit();
    }   
}
```

Click event is registered

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#register').click(function() {       
            register();
        });     
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm seeing other errors prior...
http://screencast.com/t/XkwThGbcnio1

Comment: @SethMcClaine , added addition check $.browser && $.browser.msie in jquery validation .. but ideally i should not touch the core lib... now its working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using newer version of jquery, after **jquery 1.9** 
`$.browser` has removed.

You can `download` the latest version (**Current version: 1.11.1**) of `validate plugin` to solve the problem.
Or you can use **CDN**

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js
```

or download it from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation

Read [jQuery.browser() removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed) and [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide.](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/)

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools)