# Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.colorbox.js:66

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting below exception while using jquery colorbox with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below is the exception-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.colorbox.js:66
(anonymous function) jquery.colorbox.js:66
(anonymous function) jquery.colorbox.js:814
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox' HRS_HRAM.JN_HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL&country=FRA?PortalActualURL=https%3a%2f%2fhr…fpsc%2fhrmssox%2f&PortalHostNode=HRMS&NoCrumbs=yes&PortalKeyStruct=yes:497
(anonymous function) HRS_HRAM.JN_HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL&country=FRA?PortalActualURL=https%3a%2f%2fhr…fpsc%2fhrmssox%2f&PortalHostNode=HRMS&NoCrumbs=yes&PortalKeyStruct=yes:497
c jquery.js:7341
p.fireWith jquery.js:7403
b.extend.ready jquery.js:6875
H
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? And how to fix it?

Comment: do you include the colorbox js too?

Comment: Google the error message; it seems like your plugin is using a property that is deprecated in newer jQueries. [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - jQuery tools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14923301)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [page for jQuery Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) says (emphasis mine):

> Released under the MIT License. Source on Github (changelog).
>
> **Compatible with: jQuery 1.3.2+**
> in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer 7+
> The plugin is not compatible with your version of jQuery.

It seems like the plugin is too old for jQuery 1.9.1, probably because it's using the `.browser` property.

You'll have to fix the plugin, or reintroduce the property as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14923301).

Answer (score 2):

**Simple fix:** update to the current version (https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox), which removed the browser check quite some time ago (https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox#version-1319---december-08-2011)

Comment: this is normally because of missing functions jquery.browser() in new jquery versions, jquery migration script will fix that
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: @Tofeeq Which is covered in the answer linked to by Pekka, or by updating to a version that doesn't rely on deprecated/removed functions.