# drupal overlay not closing, Edit link not loading overlay

Tags: drupal-7, content-management-system, overlay

I'm having an odd issue after having migrated my drupal project to a client's server. 
After configuring the apache http.conf to accept clean urls, I'm now finding that the administrative overlay does not always respond. 
-The Find content shortcut doesn't respond, but the Content link on the overlay does. 
-The Edit link when on a node's detail page makes the site darken like it does when the overlay is being loaded, but the Edit window for the node never appears. 
-The X (close) on an overlay page (like when using Content to see the list of all nodes, but then want to quit out of it and go back to the site) fails to close the overlay and a strange, second vertical scrollbar appears on the right of the browser screen.
I have had a similar problem before, but chalked it up to javascript on the page interfering with the overlay's own javascript. Now I'm not so sure.
If anyone else has had this problem, or can surmise what the issue might be, then I would appreciate any and all help given.

My thanks,
~M@

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you click the X to close it?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference overlay-parent.js, line 950 character 3. And wouldn't you know, after seeing this error message I tried the site out in Firefox and the overlay works fine. I should have started with the fact that the site was being viewed in IE(eee!).

Comment: Did this work out for you?

Comment: @jsheffers No sadly, it didn't work. Same problems. The overlay doesn't appear to be working in any version of IE of 7+. Here's the site - [link](http://212.219.179.220)

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I have the exact same behaviour on a site recently...

Comment: The only sure-fire way I found of having this problem go away was to turn off the overlay, which actually helps the site performance as it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are using a jQuery version that is incompatible with the overlay module.   It's probably because `$.browser` is deprecated in jQuery 1.9, see the following issue:

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - jQuery tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools)

To fix this issue, you'll need to install the latest jQuery Update module and select something below jQuery 1.9 for the admin interface.  This should clear up your problems in IE.

Comment: Latest version of jQuery Update installed. Gave me 1.5, 1.7 and 1.8 as options. Tried them all in IE7, 8, 9 and 10. Same problem each time. Here's the site again, just in case : [link](http://212.219.179.220). Ordinarily I could just chalk this up to IE being rubbish, but unfortunately the client uses IE and will likely be using the CMS via IE, so this really needs to get fixed and working. I have no clue however.

Comment: It looks as if you are using jquery-migrate, which should give you access to $.broswer.  My next guess is that you're loading multiple versions of jQuery.  Also, you have another script error on the page as well.

Comment: Okay, well, in order to try and see if the apparent multiple version of jQuery was an issue, I deactivated jQuery Update, leaving jQuery-migrate in and got the following error message `code`
Message: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js
Message: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference
URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js
Message: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference
Line: 907
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://212.219.179.220/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.js?v=1.0

Comment: Putting jQuery Update back in results in just jquery-migrate "unable to get property 'value' of undefined", so even jquery-migrate appears to be getting prevented from operating. Reaching my wits' end with this one.

Comment: I wonder if it's the foundation jquery going on at the bottom of the pages that might be causing problems?

Comment: It would be difficult to troubleshoot further without actually seeing the setup.  I would try removing jquery-migrate and the foundation call at the bottom, since both are throwing errors for me.

Comment: I found what appeared to be causing the overlay closing problem. Commenting out the Zepto call (whatever that is) at line 239 appeared to do it. However now I'm getting the odd error of `code`Webpage error details 
Message: 'Date' is undefined 
Line: 36 
Char: 373`code` Weird.