# Javascript slideshow in wordpress not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working with the site http://tradelikepros.com/ which is a wordpress site based on cherry framework. But the slideshow in the home page is not working but i see all the codes are ok. 
Can anyone help me to solve this issue
Thanks

Comment: post javaconsole log from browser for errors and related code

Comment: Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) (index):1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'touchstart' of undefined jquery.mobile.customized.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined custom.js?ver=1.0:99
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js?ver=1.8:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some javascript errors as shown in the image

[image]

it seems like you use old `jQuery` script please use jquery migration to solve this you can insert the following line into your `header` and be sure that it is after `jQuery`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: since it was mobile version, which shows the actual uncaught typeerror function:, we had to update the mobile version of JS.

from the site : https://jquerymobile.com/download/  using the latest script.  ex:

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the javascript of your page.  It seems the version of jquery that your site is using is not compatible with the code in your custom.js file.  Specifically this line

```
line 99: var MSIE8 = (jQuery.browser.msie) && (jQuery.browser.version == 8);
```

with the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

You loading your jquery via the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tradelikepros.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8"></script>
```

But that jquery.js file you are using is actually `jQuery v1.10.2`.  As you can see in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools),

> $.browser was removed from jQuery starting with version 1.9.

There is also an error in your `jquery.mobile.customized.min.js` file, but since it is minified I cannot tell exactly what is causing it.

It's possible these javascript errors are what is causing your slideshow to not function.

By the way, I got all this information by looking at your site with Chrome Developer Tools open (hit f12 on a loaded webpage and select the Console tab to see javascript output).