# Best approach for hashchange detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashchange

I want to support ajax navigation by using jQuery and the `onhashchange` event.
It looks like [Ben Alman's hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) is outdated because it relies on jQuery browser detection, [which is deprecated and not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools).

I also found the [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) library but it uses HTML5 history API which I don't want to use because I want consistent behavior for all browsers.

What is the current best approach for implementing `onhashchange` support?

Comment: From [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) homepage: *Aims: Provide a backwards-compatible experience for all HTML4 Browsers using a hash-fallback*. P.S. A list of good HTML5 polyfills can be found on the [Modernizr Github](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)