# Datepicker not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

This code is not working. I don't know what resource I need to add. I am following a link for Datepicker here:  http://jsfiddle.net/rMhVz/1030/  And my code is down below. I really need to get it to work. I appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"></link>
<style type="text/css">
.event > a { 
    background-color: gray !important;
    background-image:none !important;
}
</style>
<script>
// hookup jquery ready function
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Event = function(text, desc) {
        this.text = text;
        this.desc = desc;
    };

    var events = {};
    events[new Date("07/06/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 1");
    events[new Date("08/8/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 2");
    events[new Date("09/26/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 3");

    $("#dates").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var event = events[date];
            if (event) {
                return [true, 'event', event.text];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var event = events[new Date(dateText)];
            if (event) {
                alert(event.text + "\n" + event.desc);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dates"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include jQuery, and include it before jQuery UI. You also need to move your code to the end of your document or wrap it in a document ready call.

Comment: Include a reference to **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/)** before jQuery UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response .Can you edit the code above to include that change.I dont know how to do that.I really appreciate your help.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @j08691 can you copy/paste the abovr code and let me know whats wrong now ?

Comment: You still haven't moved your jQuery to the end of the document or wrapped it in a document ready.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ and there you put your function this goes inside the <script>

Comment: @MickyScion Please Sir can You rewrite the code above .I tried many times but unable to see anything other than the blank page.

Comment: All your script goes inside the {} of $(document).ready(function(){ } so it going to see like this <script> $(document).ready(function(){ (here copy all your script without "<script>", only the code) ) } </script>

Comment: CAn yo look at the code above and rewrite it.I am unable to make the code above work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I don't believe the script load order was the only problem. You're using incompatible versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. Your code breaks on a call to $.browser.msie. [$.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Source of error in jquery.ui:

```
html += buttonPanel + ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version,10) < 7 && !inst.inline ? '<iframe src="javascript:false;" class="ui-datepicker-cover" frameborder="0"></iframe>' : '');
```

Try using a more recent version of jQuery UI that is compatible with jQuery 1.9+.

See [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - jQuery tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools).

EDIT: For clarification, your script includes should be

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.‌​css"></link>
```

Consider using jQuery 1.9.1, but it appears to work fine with 1.9.0.

Comment: How do I fix the code above now .I am lost.Please help.

Comment: Well, start off by including jQuery UI 1.9.1 or later. That is when $.browser was removed. It should just work, as in this JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/5peJH/6/

Comment: See edit for more detailed instructions.

Comment: You're more than welcome. Dependencies can be a pain. Props to other contributors for pointing out the load order errors, too.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include jQuery. Include it before any other js or jquery file and you should be good.

Comment: I have updated the code above please have a look.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add jQuery before jQuery UI, use `<link>` instead of `<script>` for the css and use jQuery function from document.ready:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"></link>
<style type="text/css">
.event > a { 
    background-color: gray !important;
    background-image:none !important;
}
</style>
<script>
// hookup jquery ready function
$(document).ready(function () {
    var Event = function(text, desc) {
        this.text = text;
        this.desc = desc;
    };

    var events = {};
    events[new Date("07/06/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 1");
    events[new Date("08/8/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 2");
    events[new Date("09/26/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 3");

    $("#dates").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var event = events[date];
            if (event) {
                return [true, 'event', event.text];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var event = events[new Date(dateText)];
            if (event) {
                alert(event.text + "\n" + event.desc);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dates"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added that still not working.

Comment: I have updated the code above please have a look.THanks

Comment: Now you have a duplicate entry for jquery.ui. And is your server connected to the internet, does it have access to the Microsoft CDN?

Comment: sorry.Even then after removing.Check the code above it still does not work .Can you copy paste the code and execute and let me know where I am going wrong?Appreciate your help and time.Thanks

Comment: yes the script is on the server and is connected to internet

Comment: The jquery.ui style sheet needs to be included using `<link>`

Comment: I tried the code above but I still get blank page.??

Comment: still not working?? any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Include jQuery in the following order : jQuery - jQueryUI - jQueryUIcss.

   Include css files using `<link>`.

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.7/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">  </link>
   ```
2. Use `$(document).ready(..)` for your JS - so that all the execution happens after all the DOM elements are loaded.

---

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var Event = function(text, desc) {
        this.text = text;
        this.desc = desc;
    };

    var events = {};
    events[new Date("07/06/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 1");
    events[new Date("08/8/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 2");
    events[new Date("09/26/2014")] = new Event("hello world test 3");

    $("#dates").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var event = events[date];
            if (event) {
                return [true, 'event', event.text];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var event = events[new Date(dateText)];
            if (event) {
                alert(event.text + "\n" + event.desc);
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the code above and I still get a blank page.???

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: no errors .PLease check it on your system too.I really appreciate your help.