# problems with mobile navigation (max mega menu)

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, menu, navigation

i am developing a new website with a max mega menu as main navigation. it's all working, except if i go to a subpage on my mobile device (iphone), i can't access the navigation anymore. it works perfect on the main (first) page, but not on the subpages.

the main page is: http://new.4progress.ch/
an example of a subpage is: http://new.4progress.ch/course/kompetenztraining-2016/

can anyone help me with this?

initial code:

```
(function($){

if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || 
    navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) ){ 
    var gdlr_touch_device = true; 
}else{ 
    var gdlr_touch_device = false; 
}

// retrieve GET variable from url
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
}); 

// blog - port nav
function gdlr_set_item_outer_nav(){
    $('.blog-item-wrapper > .gdlr-nav-container').each(function(){
        var container = $(this).siblings('.blog-item-holder');
        var child = $(this).children();
        child.css({ 'top':container.position().top, 'bottom':'auto', height: container.height() - 50 });
    });
    $('.portfolio-item-wrapper > .gdlr-nav-container').each(function(){
        var container = $(this).siblings('.portfolio-item-holder');
        var child = $(this).children();
        child.css({ 'top':container.position().top, 'bottom':'auto', height: container.height() - 40 });
    });     
}   

// runs flex slider function
$.fn.gdlr_flexslider = function(){
    if(typeof($.fn.flexslider) == 'function'){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var flex_attr = {
                animation: 'fade',
                animationLoop: true,
                prevText: '<i class="icon-angle-left" ></i>', 
                nextText: '<i class="icon-angle-right" ></i>',
                useCSS: false
            };

            // slide duration
            if( $(this).attr('data-pausetime') ){
                flex_attr.slideshowSpeed = parseInt($(this).attr('data-pausetime'));
            }
            if( $(this).attr('data-slidespeed') ){
                flex_attr.animationSpeed = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slidespeed'));
            }

            // set the attribute for carousel type
            if( $(this).attr('data-type') == 'carousel' ){
                flex_attr.move = 1;
                flex_attr.animation = 'slide';

                if( $(this).closest('.gdlr-item-no-space').length > 0 ){
                    flex_attr.itemWidth = $(this).width() / parseInt($(this).attr('data-columns'));
                    flex_attr.itemMargin = 0;                           
                }else{
                    flex_attr.itemWidth = (($(this).width() + 30) / parseInt($(this).attr('data-columns'))) - 30;
                    flex_attr.itemMargin = 30;  
                }       

                // if( $(this).attr('data-columns') == "1" ){ flex_attr.smoothHeight = true; }
            }else{
                if( $(this).attr('data-effect') ){
                    flex_attr.animation = $(this).attr('data-effect');
                }
            }
            if( $(this).attr('data-columns') ){
                flex_attr.minItems = parseInt($(this).attr('data-columns'));
                flex_attr.maxItems = parseInt($(this).attr('data-columns'));    
            }               

            // set the navigation to different area
            if( $(this).attr('data-nav-container') ){
                var flex_parent = $(this).parents('.' + $(this).attr('data-nav-container')).prev('.gdlr-nav-container');

                if( flex_parent.find('.gdlr-flex-prev').length > 0 || flex_parent.find('.gdlr-flex-next').length > 0 ){
                    flex_attr.controlNav = false;
                    flex_attr.directionNav = false;
                    flex_attr.start = function(slider){
                        flex_parent.find('.gdlr-flex-next').click(function(){
                            slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"), true);
                        });
                        flex_parent.find('.gdlr-flex-prev').click(function(){
                            slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("prev"), true);
                        });

                        gdlr_set_item_outer_nav();
                        $(window).resize(function(){ gdlr_set_item_outer_nav(); });
                    }
                }else{
                    flex_attr.controlNav = false;
                    flex_attr.controlsContainer = flex_parent.find('.nav-container');   
                }

            }

            $(this).flexslider(flex_attr);  
        }); 
    }
}

// runs nivo slider function
$.fn.gdlr_nivoslider = function(){
    if(typeof($.fn.nivoSlider) == 'function'){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var nivo_attr = {};

            if( $(this).attr('data-pausetime') ){
                nivo_attr.pauseTime = parseInt($(this).attr('data-pausetime'));
            }
            if( $(this).attr('data-slidespeed') ){
                nivo_attr.animSpeed = parseInt($(this).attr('data-slidespeed'));
            }
            if( $(this).attr('data-effect') ){
                nivo_attr.effect = $(this).attr('data-effect');
            }

            $(this).nivoSlider(nivo_attr);  
        }); 
    }
}   

// runs isotope function
$.fn.gdlr_isotope = function(){
    if(typeof($.fn.isotope) == 'function'){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var layout = ($(this).attr('data-layout'))? $(this).attr('data-layout'): 'fitRows';
            if( layout == 'fitRows' ) return;

            // execute isotope
            var isotope_element = $(this);
            isotope_element.children('.clear').remove();
            isotope_element.isotope({
                layoutMode: layout
            });

            // resize event
            $(window).resize(function(){
                isotope_element.isotope();
            });             
        }); 
    }
}

// runs fancybox function
$.fn.gdlr_fancybox = function(){
    if(typeof($.fn.fancybox) == 'function'){
        var fancybox_attr = {
            nextMethod : 'resizeIn',
            nextSpeed : 250,
            prevMethod : false,
            prevSpeed : 250,    
            helpers : { media : {} }
        };

        if( typeof($.fancybox.helpers.thumbs) == 'object' ){
            fancybox_attr.helpers.thumbs = { width: 50, height: 50 };
        }

        $(this).fancybox(fancybox_attr);
    }   
}

// responsive video
$.fn.gdlr_fluid_video = function(){
    $(this).find('iframe[src^="http://www.youtube.com"], iframe[src^="//www.youtube.com"],'  +
                 'iframe[src^="http://player.vimeo.com"], iframe[src^="//player.vimeo.com"]').each(function(){

        if( ($(this).is('embed') && $(this).parent('object').length) || $(this).parent('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').length ){ return; } 
        if( !$(this).attr('id') ){ $(this).attr('id', 'gdlr-video-' + Math.floor(Math.random()*999999)); }

        // ignore if inside layerslider
        if( $(this).closest('.ls-container').length <= 0 ){ 
            var ratio = $(this).height() / $(this).width();
            $(this).removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
            $(this).wrap('<div class="gdlr-fluid-video-wrapper"></div>').parent().css('padding-top', (ratio * 100)+"%");
        }

    }); 
}

// pie chart
$.fn.gdlr_pie_chart = function(){
    if(typeof($.fn.easyPieChart) == 'function'){
        $(this).each(function(){
            var gdlr_chart = $(this);

            $(this).easyPieChart({
                animate: 1200,
                lineWidth: gdlr_chart.attr('data-linewidth')? parseInt(gdlr_chart.attr('data-linewidth')): 8,
                size: gdlr_chart.attr('data-size')? parseInt(gdlr_chart.attr('data-size')): 155,
                barColor: gdlr_chart.attr('data-color')? gdlr_chart.attr('data-color'): '#a9e16e',
                trackColor: gdlr_chart.attr('data-bg-color')? gdlr_chart.attr('data-bg-color'): '#f2f2f2',
                backgroundColor: gdlr_chart.attr('data-background'),
                scaleColor: false,
                lineCap: 'square'
            });

            // for responsive purpose
            if($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8)) return;
            function limit_gdlr_chart_size(){
                if( gdlr_chart.parent().width() < parseInt(gdlr_chart.attr('data-size')) ){
                    var max_width = gdlr_chart.parent().width() + 'px';
                    gdlr_chart.css({'max-width': max_width, 'max-height': max_width});
                }               
            }
            limit_gdlr_chart_size();
            $(window).resize(function(){ limit_gdlr_chart_size(); });
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // top woocommerce button
    $('.gdlr-top-woocommerce-wrapper').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('.gdlr-top-woocommerce').fadeIn(200);
    }, function(){
        $(this).children('.gdlr-top-woocommerce').fadeOut(200);
    });

    // script for accordion item
    $('.gdlr-accordion-item').each(function(){
        var multiple_tab = $(this).hasClass('gdlr-multiple-tab');
        $(this).children('.accordion-tab').children('.accordion-title').click(function(){
            var current_tab = $(this).parent();
            if( current_tab.hasClass('active') ){
                current_tab.removeClass('pre-active');
                $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
                $(this).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp(function(){ current_tab.removeClass('active'); });
            }else{
                current_tab.addClass('pre-active');
                $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');  
                $(this).siblings('.accordion-content').slideDown(function(){ current_tab.addClass('active'); });

            }

            // close another tab if multiple tab is not allowed ( accordion )
            if( !multiple_tab ){
                current_tab.siblings().removeClass('pre-active');
                current_tab.siblings().children('.accordion-title').children('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
                current_tab.siblings().children('.accordion-content').slideUp(function(){ $(this).parent().removeClass('active'); });
            }
        });
    });

    // script for tab item
    $('.tab-title-wrapper').children().click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

        var selected_index = $(this).index() + 1;
        $(this).parent().siblings('.tab-content-wrapper').children(':nth-child(' + selected_index + ')').each(function(){
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').hide();
            $(this).fadeIn(function(){ $(this).addClass('active'); });
        })
    });     

    // initiate the tab when the get tab variable is sent
    var inital_tab = $.getUrlVar('tab');
    if( inital_tab ){ $('#' + inital_tab.replace(',', ', #')).each(function(){ $(this).trigger('click'); }); }

    // script for code item
    $('.gdlr-code-item .gdlr-code-title').click(function(){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        if( parent.hasClass('active') ){
            $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
            $(this).siblings('.gdlr-code-content').slideUp(function(){
                parent.removeClass('active');
            }); 
        }else{
            $(this).children('i').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
            $(this).siblings('.gdlr-code-content').slideDown(function(){
                parent.addClass('active');  
            });             
        }
    });     

    // script for parallax background
    $('.gdlr-parallax-wrapper').each(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('gdlr-background-image') ){
            var parallax_section = $(this);
            var parallax_speed = parseFloat(parallax_section.attr('data-bgspeed'));
            if( parallax_speed == 0 || gdlr_touch_device ) return;
            if( parallax_speed == -1 ){
                parallax_section.css('background-attachment', 'fixed');
                parallax_section.css('background-position', 'center center');
                return;
            }

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                // if in area of interest
                if( ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > parallax_section.offset().top ) &&
                    ( $(window).scrollTop() < parallax_section.offset().top + parallax_section.outerHeight() ) ){

                    var scroll_pos = 0;
                    if( $(window).height() > parallax_section.offset().top ){
                        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
                    }else{
                        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - parallax_section.offset().top;
                    }
                    parallax_section.css('background-position', 'center ' + (-scroll_pos * parallax_speed) + 'px');
                }
            });         
        }else if( $(this).hasClass('gdlr-background-video') ){
            if(typeof($.fn.mb_YTPlayer) == 'function'){
                $(this).children('.gdlr-bg-player').mb_YTPlayer();
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }
    });

    // video responsive
    $('body').gdlr_fluid_video();       

    // runs superfish menu
    if(typeof($.fn.superfish) == 'function'){

        // create the mega menu script
        $('#gdlr-main-navigation .sf-mega > ul').each(function(){   
            $(this).children('li').each(function(){
                var current_item = $(this);
                current_item.replaceWith(
                    $('<div />').addClass('sf-mega-section')
                                .addClass(current_item.attr('data-column'))
                                .attr('data-size', current_item.attr('data-size'))
                                .html(  $('<div />').addClass('sf-mega-section-inner')
                                                    .addClass(current_item.attr('class'))
                                                    .attr('id', current_item.attr('id'))
                                                    .html(current_item.html())
                                )       
                );
            });
            $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
        });

        // make every menu same height
        $('#gdlr-main-navigation .sf-mega').each(function(){
            var sf_mega = $(this); $(this).show();

            var row = 0; var column = 0; var max_height = 0;
            sf_mega.children('.sf-mega-section').each(function(){
                if( column % 60 == 0 ){ 
                    if( row != 0 ){
                        sf_mega.children('[data-row="' + row + '"]').children('.sf-mega-section-inner').height( max_height - 50 );
                        max_height = 0;
                    }
                    row++; $(this).addClass('first-column'); 
                }       

                $(this).attr('data-row', row);  
                column += eval('60*' + $(this).attr('data-size'));

                if( $(this).height() > max_height ){
                    max_height = $(this).height();
                }
            });

            sf_mega.children('[data-row="' + row + '"]').children('.sf-mega-section-inner').height( max_height - 50 );      
        });

        $('#gdlr-main-navigation').superfish({
            delay: 100, 
            speed: 'fast', 
            animation: {opacity:'show', height:'show'}
        });     
    }

    // responsive menu
    if(typeof($.fn.dlmenu) == 'function'){
        $('#gdlr-responsive-navigation').each(function(){
            $(this).find('.dl-submenu').each(function(){
                if( $(this).siblings('a').attr('href') && $(this).siblings('a').attr('href') != '#' ){
                    var parent_nav = $('<li class="menu-item gdlr-parent-menu"></li>');
                    parent_nav.append($(this).siblings('a').clone());

                    $(this).prepend(parent_nav);
                }
            });
            $(this).dlmenu();
        });
    }   

    // gallery thumbnail type
    $('.gdlr-gallery-thumbnail').each(function(){
        var thumbnail_container = $(this).children('.gdlr-gallery-thumbnail-container');

        $(this).find('.gallery-item').click(function(){
            var selected_slide = thumbnail_container.children('[data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '"]');
            if(selected_slide.css('display') == 'block') return false;

            // check the gallery height
            var image_width = selected_slide.children('img').attr('width');
            var image_ratio = selected_slide.children('img').attr('height') / image_width;
            var temp_height = image_ratio * Math.min(thumbnail_container.width(), image_width);

            thumbnail_container.animate({'height': temp_height});
            selected_slide.fadeIn().siblings().hide();
            return false;
        });     

        $(window).resize(function(){ thumbnail_container.css('height', 'auto') });
    });

    // fancybox
    $('a[href$=".jpg"], a[href$=".png"], a[href$=".gif"]').not('[data-rel="fancybox"]').attr('data-rel', 'fancybox');
    $('[data-rel="fancybox"]').gdlr_fancybox();

    // image shortcode 
    $('.gdlr-image-link-shortcode').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.gdlr-image-link-overlay').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 150);
        $(this).find('.gdlr-image-link-icon').animate({opacity: 1}, 150);
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.gdlr-image-link-overlay').animate({opacity: 0}, 150);
        $(this).find('.gdlr-image-link-icon').animate({opacity: 0}, 150);
    }); 

    // Personnel
    $('.gdlr-personnel-item.round-style .personnel-item').each(function(){
        var current_item = $(this);
        function gdlr_set_round_personnel_height(){
            current_item.find('.personnel-item-inner').each(function(){
                $(this).css('margin-top', -($(this).height()/2));
            });
        }

        gdlr_set_round_personnel_height();
        $(window).resize(function(){
            gdlr_set_round_personnel_height();
        });
    });
    $('.gdlr-personnel-item.round-style .personnel-item').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.personnel-author-image').animate({'opacity':0.05}, 200);
        $(this).find('.personnel-item-inner').animate({'opacity':1}, 200);
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('.personnel-author-image').animate({'opacity':1}, 200);
        $(this).find('.personnel-item-inner').animate({'opacity':0}, 200);
    });

    // Price Table
    $('.gdlr-price-table-item').each(function(){
        var price_table = $(this);

        function set_price_table_height(){
            var max_height = 0;
            var price_content = price_table.find('.price-content');

            price_content.css('height', 'auto');
            price_content.each(function(){
                if( max_height < $(this).height() ){ max_height = $(this).height(); }
            });
            price_content.css('height', max_height);
        }

        set_price_table_height()
        $(window).resize(function(){ set_price_table_height(); });
    });

    // Default text
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var has_default = false;
        $(this).find('input[data-default]').each(function(){
            if( $(this).is('#url') ){
                if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default') ) $(this).val('');
            }else{
                if( $(this).val() == $(this).attr('data-default') ) has_default = true;
            }
        });

        if(has_default) return false;
    }); 

    // Search option
    $('#gdlr-nav-search-form-button').click(function(){
        $('#gdlr-nav-search-form').slideToggle(200);
        return false;
    });
    $('#gdlr-nav-search-form').click(function(event){
        if(event.stopPropagation){
            event.stopPropagation();
        }else if(window.event){
            window.event.cancelBubble=true;
        }
    });
    $("html").click(function(){
        $('#gdlr-nav-search-form').slideUp(200);
    });         
    $('.search-text input[data-default], .gdlr-comments-area input[data-default]').each(function(){
        var default_value = $(this).attr("data-default");
        $(this).val(default_value);
        $(this).live("blur", function(){
            if ($(this).val() == ""){
                $(this).val(default_value);
            }   
        }).live("focus", function(){
            if ($(this).val() == default_value){
                $(this).val("");
            }
        });     
    });     

    // smooth anchor
    if( window.location.hash ){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top - 68
        }, 500);
    }
    $('.gdlr-navigation a[href^="#"], .gdlr-responsive-navigation a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
        if( $(this).attr('href').length > 1 ){
            var item_id = $($(this).attr('href'));

            if( $('body').hasClass('home') ){
                if( item_id.length > 0 ){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: item_id.offset().top - 68
                    }, 500);
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                window.location.replace($('.body-wrapper').attr('data-home') + '/' + $(this).attr('href'));
            }
        }
    }); 

    // animate ux
    if( !gdlr_touch_device && ( !$.browser.msie || (parseInt($.browser.version) > 8)) ){

        // image ux
        $('.content-wrapper img').each(function(){
            if( $(this).closest('.gdlr-ux, .ls-wp-container, .product, .flexslider, .nivoSlider').length ) return;

            var ux_item = $(this);
            if( ux_item.offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ){
                ux_item.css({ 'opacity':0 });
            }else{ return; }

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ux_item.offset().top + 100 ){
                    ux_item.animate({ 'opacity':1 }, 1200); 
                }
            });                 
        });

        // item ux
        $('.gdlr-ux').each(function(){
            var ux_item = $(this);
            if( ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-chart') || ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-skill-bar') ){
                if( ux_item.offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ){
                    if( ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-chart') && (!$.browser.msie || (parseInt($.browser.version) > 8)) ){
                        ux_item.gdlr_pie_chart();
                    }else if( ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-skill-bar') ){
                        ux_item.children('.gdlr-skill-bar-progress').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-percent')){
                                $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('data-percent') + '%'}, 1200, 'easeOutQuart');
                            }
                        }); 
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }else if( ux_item.offset().top > $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ){
                ux_item.css({ 'opacity':0, 'padding-top':20, 'margin-bottom':-20 });
            }else{ return; }    

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ux_item.offset().top + 100 ){
                    if( ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-chart') && (!$.browser.msie || (parseInt($.browser.version) > 8)) ){
                        ux_item.gdlr_pie_chart();
                    }else if( ux_item.hasClass('gdlr-skill-bar') ){
                        ux_item.children('.gdlr-skill-bar-progress').each(function(){
                            if($(this).attr('data-percent')){
                                $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('data-percent') + '%'}, 1200, 'easeOutQuart');
                            }
                        }); 
                    }else{
                        ux_item.animate({ 'opacity':1, 'padding-top':0, 'margin-bottom':0 }, 1200);
                    }
                }
            });                 
        });

    // do not animate on scroll in mobile
    }else{

        // Pie chart
        if(!$.browser.msie || (parseInt($.browser.version) > 8)){
            $('.gdlr-chart').gdlr_pie_chart();
        }   


        // skill bar
        $('.gdlr-skill-bar-progress').each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('data-percent')){
                $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('data-percent') + '%'}, 1200, 'easeOutQuart');
            }
        });         
    }       

    // runs nivoslider when available
    $('.nivoSlider').gdlr_nivoslider();     

    // runs flexslider when available
    $('.flexslider').gdlr_flexslider();

});

$(window).load(function(){

    // run isotope when available
    $('.gdlr-isotope').gdlr_isotope();  

    // run pie chart for ie8 and below
    if($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8)){
        $('.gdlr-chart').gdlr_pie_chart();
    }   

    // float menu
    $('.body-wrapper.float-menu').each(function(){
        var sub_area = $('#gdlr-header-substitute');
        var main_area = sub_area.siblings('.gdlr-header-wrapper');

        var logo = main_area.find('.gdlr-logo');
        var logo_img = main_area.find('.gdlr-logo img');
        var navigation = main_area.find('.gdlr-navigation-wrapper');                
        var original = {
            logo_top: logo.css('margin-top'), 
            logo_bottom: logo.css('margin-bottom'), 
            nav_top: navigation.css('margin-top')
        };

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( main_area.hasClass('gdlr-fixed-header') && ($(this).scrollTop() == 0 || $(this).width() < 959)){
                main_area.children('.top-navigation-wrapper').slideDown(100);

                logo.animate({'margin-top': original.logo_top, 'margin-bottom': original.logo_bottom}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
                logo_img.animate({'width': '100%'}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
                navigation.animate({'margin-top': original.nav_top}, {duration: 100, queue: false, 
                    complete: function(){
                        sub_area.css('height', 'auto');
                        main_area.removeClass('gdlr-fixed-header');

                        navigation.removeAttr("style");
                        logo.removeAttr("style");
                    }
                });                             
            }else if( !main_area.hasClass('gdlr-fixed-header') && $(this).width() > 959 &&
                $(this).scrollTop() > main_area.children('.gdlr-header-inner').offset().top - parseInt($('html').css('margin-top')) ){
                    sub_area.css('height', main_area.height());
                    main_area.addClass('gdlr-fixed-header');
                    main_area.children('.top-navigation-wrapper').hide();

                    logo.animate({'margin-top': '20', 'margin-bottom': '23'}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
                    logo_img.animate({'width': '80%'}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
                    navigation.animate({'margin-top': '25'}, {duration: 100, queue: false});
            }               
        });
    });         

    $(window).trigger('resize');
    $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a typo in your JS code. Check your console, these errors appears on the subpage, but not the main page.

```
$(...).live is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

Comment: sorry, but i am really not good in JS. would you be able to tell me what i could change (or which script i should look at)?

Comment: Ok, i guess you just used a plugin or did you fiddle around with some JS yourself?

Comment: yes i used a plugin (max mega menu for wordpress) and also different other plugins on that site. would you be able to help me with looking into the problem?

Comment: The most obvious error source would be [deprication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14354091/3880255). Your function uses [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), but should use, by newer standards [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). In your script `gdlr-script.js?ver=3c4c04112b199064b994397301d9c8a0:508` you have a function using `.live`. I suppose a plugin you are using is rather old and still uses that function, try changing it to `.on` and see if it works.

Comment: can i just change that by changing the .live to .on?

Comment: Yes, just try changing this exact line : `$(this).live("blur", function(){` to `$(this).on("blur", function(){` and tell me if that fixed the problem.

Comment: And i just found another error, another [deprication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923480/3880255). You really are using some old code, these code snippets have to be in about 3 years old. On this line `gdlr-script.js?ver=3c4c04112b199064b994397301d9c8a0:629` you get another error, try removing `if($.browser.msie && (parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8)){` and leave it like that: `if((parseInt($.browser.version) <= 8)){`.

Comment: i changed those two functions but the problem still exists. any other suggestion?

Comment: Update it to your live version so i can see if any other errors are thrown, when i open your page these two errors still exist.

Comment: Everything in your code seems to be deprecated .. If you want to remove the support for extremely old browsers you can remove some lines in your code or use a [modern method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965091/3880255).

Comment: Line 543: `if( !gdlr_touch_device){`. Line 629: Completely remove these thre if statement and change to `$('.gdlr-chart').gdlr_pie_chart();`. Try this, if it won't work you can still roll back and i can try to find the problem somehwere else.

Comment: happy to help, just feed me some reputation and i'm a happy man `:P`

Comment: i am sorry to bother you again, but i just realized that it now work on mobile devices, but the navigation doesn't minimize on the main page anymore. check out: http://new.4progress.ch/course/kompetenztraining-2016/

Comment: Another error in your JS code `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. Provide me with your inital code and what you have now, i cannot find a syntax error if i don't have the inital code. You probably just removed a character too much.

Comment: the new code you can see here: [link](/new.4progress.ch/wp-content/uploads/gdlr-script.txt)

Comment: i think i just found the mistake. i had to remove an else argument:

     
  else{
  
   // Pie chart
   $('.gdlr-chart').gdlr_pie_chart();
  
   $('.gdlr-skill-bar-progress').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-percent')){
     $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('data-percent') + '%'}, 1200, 'easeOutQuart');
    }
   });   
  }

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't find the if statement to that either, but was just assuming. Working sweet now i guess. Oh and `Grüezi: D`

Comment: Yeah guessed you knew german, still explained in english, i'm from Austria just right next to Switzerland, so a `Zeawas` from me, ha!