# document.write() in a Fancybox 1 window

Tags: php, fancybox

Probably I'm misunderstanding something about Fancybox v1 but have the following minor issue. First I'm calling fancybox via clicking a link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".href").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
      href : $(this).attr("data-id"),
      type : 'iframe'
    });
  });
});
```

This loads a simple PHP/HTML page with JS, to be populated into the Fancybox window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head>
<body>
<?php
# this is the fancybox content 
echo "<script>var dcwrtext = 'random_text'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script> Some other content to show on fancybox.";
?>
</body></html>
```

The content appears without a problem, but the nuance is, the `document.write` value is echoed after the closing `</script>` tag: and this makes the content visible on the page, not the `document.write()` function. You can see this in the source code:

```
<body>
<script>var dcwrtext = 'random_text'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script>**random_text** Some other content to show on fancybox.
</body>
```

The problem seems to be with fancybox, if I use the `document.write()` on a standard HTML (not fancyboxed) page, as expected, it will correctly show 'random_text' on the page, inside `<script></script>` only. This is the source code:

```
<body>
<script>var dcwrtext = 'random_text'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script> Some other content to show on fancybox.
</body>
```

What I'd need is if I open the fancbox window, 'random_text' shouldn't appear literally after the closing `</script>` tag, but would be displayed only by the document.write() function.

Comment: Is it an option to upgrade fancybox? I tried with Version 2.1.3 and it looks ok.

Comment: How did you do it? I downloaded the 2.1.5, modified the iframe.html of the 'Open single gallery item, custom options' demo. Then if I put the <script>var dcwrtext = 'random_text'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script> either to the head or body, the textual 'random_text' still appears. http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/01/31/56ae1ad112333.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tested:

main page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.2" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-id="fancy.php" class="href">open fancy</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  $(".href").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
      href : $(this).attr("data-id"),
      type : 'iframe'
    });
  });
});
</script>
<div id="theid" class="fancybox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the page being opened in fancybox: fancy.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$randomtext = "random_text";
echo "<script>var dcwrtext = '$randomtext'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script>Some other content to show on fancybox";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[I had to include `jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js` because of an error [ [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools)] when including newer versions of jquery with fancybox]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the help, I tried your code but if I highlight the "random_textSome other content to show on fancybox" on the fancybox layer, then open the source, the 'random_text is still there: <script>var dcwrtext = 'random_text'; document.write(dcwrtext);</script>random_textSome other content to show on fancybox. Nonetheless I'll approach this from some other ways, thanks again.