# Wordpress - slider not working after update

Tags: wordpress, slider

this is the website that was Assigned to me can you please help me fix the slider I don't know what is causing the error.

http://www.kentcnc.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your jquery is wrong, fix it. Check [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) maybe the path is wrong there, find the right directory and change it.

You can also search for it in your header.php file this is how your head looks:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script> <!--this line is wrong!-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,400italic,600,700|Sanchez' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Kent CNC - CNC Machining Centers and Turning Centers</title>
```

I don't think wp_enqueue_script was used to set it there. Find where it is and set the right path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I'll try.

Comment: Look in your functions.php file if it's not there, check header.php, head.php or any custom.php. If you don't find then log into your application through command line use egrep -R "jquery-1.12.2.min.js" in you /wp-content/themes/yourtheme folder. The egrep -R command can also be used to find the jquery file in your wordpress directory.

 You're welcome, don't mind to ask again in case even with that you don't find it.

Comment: I tried using a cdn for jquery 1.12.2 but still no luck. I think it's the msie property thing in the console but I don't know what I should modify.

Comment: Do you know where jquery 1.12.2 is located in your server? I mean, it's directory path.

Comment: sadly they just gave me the wordpress access. That's the only thing I have. The jquery 1.12.2 404 error is gone already when I used the cdn

Comment: This is what you need [msie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools)

Follow this and try to use jquery migrate