# Problem with Semantic UI Dropdown Box - Works in Jfiddle, but not locally

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

This Jfiddle accomplishes what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/3kpjt0xd/2/

But when I put the exact same thing into a local file and load it in a web browser, it doesn't work (one any major browser type).

What am I doing wrong? Is it the jquery? I believe all of the dependencies are loaded correctly. Is it the script at the end?

```
    <script src="https://terminal.jcubic.pl/js/jquery.terminal-0.4.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://terminal.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.terminal.css">
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form class="ui form segment">
    <div class="field">
        <label>States</label>
        <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="" id="multi-select">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="ui primary submit button">Submit</div>
    <p class="ui error message"></p>
</form>



    <script>
        $('#multi-select').dropdown();
    </script>
```

Comment: Open dev tools, then network tab, are there any resources that haven't loaded correctly there?

Comment: You need to provide more info. It's no good you just pasting a working JSFiddle and saying _"it doesn't work"_, **show us your code**, and **what you've tried so far**

Comment: That is exactly my code above. I'm guessing you don't want me to provide all variations of what I have tried so far, but I have included all of the info as to what I'm trying.

Comment: Include your error message next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your missing a library.

There are 4 scripts you need, based on that demo:

- `jquery.terminal-0.4.6.min.js`, from [here](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/js/jquery.terminal-0.4.6.min.js)
- `jquery.terminal.css` from [here](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/css/jquery.terminal.css)
- `semantic.js` from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.js)
- `semantic.min.css` from [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css)

Open up dev tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows, Linux). Then click **Network** tab. Reload the page, and observe which files are failing to load.

Comment: This is what I am getting: jquery2.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
    at jquery2.js:42
    at jquery2.js:77
(anonymous) @ jquery2.js:42
(anonymous) @ jquery2.js:77
semantic.js:22196 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
12:77 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
    at 12:77
(anonymous) @ 12:77

Comment: Right, that is more useful... this is the type of thing you should have put in your question. Here is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools