# Sub-Menu on Wordpress is not showing when I hover

Tags: html, wordpress

I recently updated my wordpress since it has been awhile and now my submenus are not showing when I hover.  I looked up and down for answers and pretty much come to a dead end.  Can anyone help me find where the issue maybe at?  The website is [www.erickeitel.com](http://www.erickeitel.com)

SubMenus

[image]

Coding

Answer (score 0):

`$.browser` & `jQuery.browser` are deprecated. So, you have to upgrade your resources with the latest one.

If you want to continue with your existing code,

```
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
    jQuery.browser.msie = false;
    jQuery.browser.version = 0;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
        jQuery.browser.msie = true;
        jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
    }
})();
```

Add this script with your script. [@Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16972927/9965724)

You can use the [jQuery-migrate](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-migrate) plugin too.

Comment: This answer doesn't address his issues with WordPress, but is more general with jQuery migrate.

Comment: The issue is because of jQuery-migrate. If you place the above script the issue will be solved.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: If it's helpful to him, I think it's. Thank you for your feedback, I will improve my base.

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress specifically, you need this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/

This is not a fix, but a work around, as WordPress 5.5 removed jQuery migrate from core.

I would personally just remove that code from your theme, as support for older versions of IE is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: That plugin fixed it!  Thank you for your time with this!